# HTTP 401 Unauthorized when calling web method using a personal token as authorization

Tags: postman, access-token, webapi, bearer-token, http-status-code-401

I am trying to call this [web api](https://api.esios.ree.es/indicator/getting_a_list_of_indicators) using [postman](https://www.postman.com). In order to use it you must apply for a personal token via email before (see [here](https://api.esios.ree.es) at the beginning of the page indicated as "Personal token request", you must send an email requesting a personal token).

So I have requested a personal token and once I have it I am trying to call above indicated method, [this one](https://api.esios.ree.es/indicator/getting_a_list_of_indicators).

So I configure postman as below screenshots show. I only fill in the Authorization (with my token) and the headers tabs. I indicate GET as verb and as url: https://api.esios.ree.es/indicators

Authorization:

[image]

Headers:

[image]

When I send the request I get error:

> HTTP Token: Access denied.

[image]

**UPDATED**:

[image]

It doesn't work...

**UPDATED - ATTEMPT #2**
Finally I have solved it by setting authorization "No Auth" in Authorization tab and instead set Authorization token in the header tab.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your value for the Token header of the format ```Token token="[token]"``` as described in the docs, or is it just the token value (which is not correct I believe)? You're hiding the entire field, so we can't see that.

Comment: @maxeth The token header has the same format as described in the docs, that is, Token token="my token here". I have updated the screenshot.

Comment: The screenshot you’ve added indicates the value you’ve passed for the `Token` header isn’t correct. You don’t need to include the leading `Token` string within the value field; Postman already prepends that as part of your configuration (as indicated by its presence on the left of the value input). You also appear to have a white space between the `token` and `=` strings in your header value; while this isn’t necessarily an issue it could cause some heartburn if the receiving server isn’t configured to handle that edge case correctly, and I would recommend removing it.

Comment: @esqew Ok, I have not included the leadin Token string within the value field. See my updated post with the screenshot. Regarding to white space between the token and = strings in the header value, I have removed it, so now no white space is there. After doing this, I receive same error message.

Comment: Can you examine your raw outgoing request to see what the headers actually look like? Since you have selected Bearer Token, I'd expect Postman to prepend `Bearer` to the value, which you apparently don't want. If that's what happened, then I think you want to use a purely custom header instead, so that it has the format in the document you linked to.

Comment: @Noah Finally I have solved. I have set authorization to "No Auth" in Authorization tab and instead set Authorization token in the header tab. See my updated "UPDATED - ATTEMPT #2". So what is the difference from setting authorization token in authorization tab and setting it in the header tab?